# Add multiple rows in ng-grid cell programatically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, split, line-breaks, ng-grid

How can I add (programatically) **multiple text rows** in a **ng-grid cell** ?

The ng-grid is created in the following way:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'myArray',
    ...
}
```

where `myArray` is a JSON array created by me using something like this:

```
function returnJsonArray(size){
    var d = [];
    ...
    for ( var i = 0 ; i < size ; i++ ) {
        values = ['VALUE TO SPLIT', ...];
        d.push(createJsonObject(keys, values);
    }
    return d;
}
```

According to the above example there is "VALUE TO SPLIT" in every cell that is in the first column. I **want to have**:

```
+-------+-------+
| VALUE |       |
| TO    |   ?   |
| SPLIT |       |
+-------+-------+
| VALUE |       |
| TO    |   ?   |
| SPLIT |       |
+-------+-------+
```

instead of

```
+---------------+-------+
| VALUE TO SPLIT|   ?   |
+---------------+-------+
| VALUE TO SPLIT|   ?   |
+---------------+-------+
```

I tried to use `<br/>` (in `values = ['VALUE<br/>TO<br/>SPLIT',...];`), but it is considered to be part of my text.

By default, the resulted DOM contains a lot of divs:

```
...
    <div class="ngCellText col0 colt0" ng-class="col.colIndex()">                           
        <span ng-cell-text="" class="ng-binding">VALUE TO SPLIT</span>
    </div>
...
```

I am not interested in how the new output will be in DOM (it can use `<span>` + `<br/>` + `<span>` or `<br/>` can be in the middle of the text).

Comment: I don't get what you want. Having multi line text in a ng-grid cell or generating some new rows?

Comment: I edited the description. I want to have multiple lines of text in a cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want dynamical row heights, ng-grid is not the best choice. It simulates a table layout with div grids that have a fixed height and are NOT measured at runtime. Better switch to a HTML table based solution like [ng-table](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/1).

Anyhow, regarding your question, this would be a solution:

- Use fixed `rowHeight` in gridOptions to best match your largest rowHeight
- Create a filter that replaces the spaces in the text `<br>`
- Use a `cellTemplate` that uses that filter

Here is a simple filter:

```
app.filter('splitAtSpaces', function() {
  return function(text, length, end) {
    if (text) {
      return text.split(' ').join('<br>');
    }
  }
});
```

This is the cellTemplate:

```
var splitTpl = '<div class="ngCellText" ng-bind-html="row.getProperty(col.field)|splitAtSpaces"></div>'
```

And here are the gridOptions with best (guessed) height values:

```
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'myData',
    rowHeight: 90,
    columnDefs: [{
      field: 'name',
      displayName: 'Name',
      cellTemplate: splitTpl
    }, {
      field: 'age',
      displayName: 'Age'
    }]
  };
```

And a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2lLPWmFkZ7FagzfS8OtY?p=preview) to show how everything works together.

**NOTE:**

- Look out for the inclusion and injection of ng-sanitize!
- If you are using another version of angularJs `ng-bind-html` may be obsolete/not implemented (*Aargh, I lost track of this security measures a while ago!*) If your output shows `<br>` instead of doing an actual line break look around on SO. There are MANY more answers to this issue.

Uhh, yes. I nearly forgot to tell you how to change the css so the divider fits your new rowHeight:

```
.ngVerticalBar {
 height: 100%;
}
```

Come back with more detailed questions once you get this running. But overall I strongly suggest you use an other table/grid directive.